# How to add search button in wordpress Menu

Tags: wordpress

I want a search button at the right side of the primary menu which display a searchbox under primary menu once it is clicked.I am a newbie in wordpress and only know html and php basic.Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: If you give https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask a quick read you'll see that you didn't provide most of the information needed for a "good question".  If you edit this and add in as much of that as you can, then you'll get much better responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add the Custom Items into your menu , Then you should use the filter hook `wp_nav_menu_items`.

**Please see the below Code and paste it into the current active theme functions.php file :**

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','add_search_box_into_menu', 10, 2);

function add_search_box_into_menu( $nav, $args ) {

    if( $args->theme_location == 'primary' )
        $nav .= '<li class="custom-header-search"><form action="'.home_url( "/" ).' id="searchform" method="get"><input type="text" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Search"></form></li>';

    return $nav;
}
```

For more help : [See here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_nav_menu_items/)

Comment: Thank you! It helps me a lot.

Comment: @CYBER , please mark as an answer if it help you to resolve you issue, so it helps other developer too. :)

Comment: I didn't know that as I am new to stackoverflow . Thank for head up :D

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add not just a link, but the search form.

To do so, you need to customize your theme.

**Important:** if you use a theme you didn't create, then first create a [child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) and modify it (it will ensure you that your changes are still applied ethen if the theme recieve updated).

Then in the HTML/PHP code where you menu is, you can use the [get_search_form()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_search_form/) method to display the search form in place.

If you want to customize the search form, juste create a searchform.php file in your theme folder and customize it.
More informations here : https://codex.wordpress.org/Styling_Theme_Forms